# Wiki software being used by Gnome

Tags: wiki

Which Wiki software is being used by Gnome? It looks really slick and clean.

https://wiki.gnome.org/

It seems they are not using MediaWiki, though I may be wrong.

Comment: ([Meta discussion](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/818/60).)

Comment: Please note that this site is about *Software Recommendation*, not "Software Identification*. You're probably looking for something similar to what's used there, but we will need much more information to give good recommendations here (you cannot expect us to figure which specific features/requirements you're after ;) Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: I am reopening this question as per https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/818/is-software-identification-on-topic/820#820

Comment: @Gilles I object [as per other meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2362/185) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use [MoinMoin](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MoinMoin). It is coded in Python (and [Python community wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Community) looks even slicker). Not sure your question is on-topic here though.

Comment: We are discussing this issue on [Meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/818/software-identification-on-topic), please come and share your opinion)/